# Able to run jar on Mac and Windows but not Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar

I have compiled a fat jar using the `shadow` plugin for gradle.

The same file works perfectly fine on both Mac and Windows, but when I try to run it on Ubuntu it says `Error: Could not find or load main class blobsaver.Main`. I'm using Java 8 on all platforms.

How do I get more details on this error? Using the `-verbose` option doesn't tell me anything useful.

```
$ java -verbose -jar blobsaver-1.2.jar
...
[Loaded java.text.Format$Field from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.text.MessageFormat$Field from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
Error: Could not find or load main class blobsaver.Main
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
```

Comment: Check which files are in the jar on each computer with `jar -tf`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt The files are the exact same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that OpenJDK does not install JavaFX by default but Oracle JDK does, so I had to install it with `sudo apt-get install openjfx`.